# Openstack Ansible Neutron issue

Tags: ini

I am trying to deploy Openstack with the help of ansible-playbooks. I am new to openstack. I have encountered some issues while I am deploying openstack, but I fixed it. Now I have my openstack environment available. But my issue is I am able to create a network but I am unable to spin up an instance with that network. But when I spin up a instance with out network I am able to run a VM successfully. I checked the nova compute logs and I found that there is issue in neutron. I checked neutron logs and I found there is an entry missing in ml2 plugin. 
Do you have any idea about ansible openstack installation.
 if yes can you please help me out.

Comment: Where did you find these scripts? Hard to say without them. If you are installing Openstack Kilo, this is the page to follow to configure the ml2 plugin: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron-network-node.html. What kind of network are you building? Flat? GRE? VLAN?

Comment: Hi Carvalho. Now I am able to create networks and spin up a VM with that particulal network.  But found a new issue. I cannot ping VM from any of my node.   My VM console is not working too. I found it is using Spice but not sure why I cannot open VM console.